# Reset history in html when on home page?

Tags: android, html, cordova

Okay, I'm making app with phonegap, and in the app I have a home button which goes to the home screen of the app, but if I click the back key after I touched the home button it goes to the page I was on before I clicked the home button, is it possible to reset the history when you navigate to the homepage? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't clear the history.
You can listen for back button event:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

and stop the propagation.

Comment: how to land to a specific screen using this?

Comment: Do you want to redirect on another page when you press the back button ? try document.location = "otherpage.html"

Answer (score 0):

The link below recommends using location.replace(url) instead of replacing the history completely, which I'm not sure is possible anyway. However, given that this is a constrained environment (an app) wiping the history might make sense - again, if possible if you're in an app.

[Clear browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288703/clear-browser-history)

Alternatively, couldn't you just remove the back key and replace it with a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

inside the event handler of the button which takes you to home:

```
startActivity(activityForHome); //I guess you already have this line
finish();  //now add this line
```