# How to disable Browser refresh and back button event in ADF using Java script

Tags: javascript, java, oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want to prevent user to click on browser back or refresh button. so for that i want to disable these events so that user can not reload or refresh or back current page.

Kindly suggest .

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167352/how-to-go-to-previous-page-in-task-flow-using-back-button-in-browser/14661853) on SO.
Disabling the back button in the browser is hard or impossible depending on what you actually want, see [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/). If you are going to do it in raw JS, then call the JS from ADF, examples [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/1-2011-javascript-302460.pdf), plus many more examples via google.

ADF includes declarative support for dis-allowing returning into a taskflow that you have navigated out of by setting the taskflow metadata in conjunction with the taskflow return component setting, details [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/raghuyadav/entry/adf_taskflow_reentry-not-allow).

Comment: Thanks for reply joe