# Dynamically add href on <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a logout  link

```
  <div id="titleInfo">
      <div id="signOut">
          <a href="" class="signOutLink"  >Log Out</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I need to add navigation destination dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Navigation Handling
    $('.signOutLink').click(function() {
        alert('h');
        window.location.href("LogOut.aspx");
        //window.location.replace("LogOut.aspx");

    });
});
```

But it is not working. How can we correct it?

Comment: `return false;` after the redirect statement

Comment: What is the aim of this? If you add `href` attribute on a `click` event, it will not go to the logout page. If you add a `return false` in the end, it will never go there. If you do not add `return false`, it will go there on clicking for the second time!

Comment: @Abhilash the question is using `window.location.href`, it doesn't change the href of the link

Comment: Also i'm not sure but i always used `window.location.href = url;`. (url pointing the full url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all.  I used following:

```
$('.signOutLink').click(function () {
    window.location.href("LogOut.aspx?a=b"); //Can use REPLACE also
    return false;  //FALSE

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.signOutLink').click(function () {
        window.location = "LogOut.aspx";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.signOutLink').click(function () {
    window.location = 'LogOut.aspx';
});

);
```

Comment: This wont work...you are using `Id` operand is having `class`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); //or grab it by tagname etc
a.href = "somelink url"
```

See ["How can I add “href” attribute to a link dynamically using javascript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689344/how-can-i-add-href-attribute-to-a-link-dynamically-using-javascript) or you can use `element.setAttribute` (see [Mozilla Developer Network's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)).

```
<div id="titleInfo">
    <div id="signOut">
        <a href="" id="signOutLink"  >Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Navigation Handling
    $('#signOutLink').click(function () {
        alert('h');
        $('#signOutLink').attr("href", "LogOut.aspx");
     });
});
```

Comment: instead of using `document.getElementById('id')` you can use jQuery's ID selector like `$('#id')`

Comment: And instead of `.setAttribute`, OP can use `.prop()` or `.attr()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
> $('.signOutLink').attr('href', 'LogOut.aspx')
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was asking for the end goal of this code is this:

If all you want is to go to a location on clicking a link and you want to assign the url dynamically, you don't need to do it in the `click()` event. It can be done simply by setting the property in the `.ready()` event lik so,

`$('a.signOutLink').prop('href','LogOut.aspx'); // or using the .attr() method`

That way, once you click on the link, it will just follow the url as it is set in the `href`